# Preventing iOS 7 UINavigationBar from animating barTintColor change with UIAppearance

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

I'd like to change every `UINavigationBar`'s `barTintColor` with no animation. Is this possible?

On iOS 7, `UINavigationBar` animates `barTintColor` changes if it is translucent. If translucent is set to `NO`, the `barTintColor` is changed, and then translucent is set back to `YES`, then it will change the bar tint without animation.

Is there any way to achieve something similar when using the `UIAppearance` proxy? Translucence can't be changed using `UIAppearance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `barTintColor` to `nil` first seemed to work. Odd...

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor magentaColor];
```